# What is the Mass Effect 3 Value for Miranda to edit in Save Edtior

Tags: mass-effect-3, pc

I'm trying to toggle Miranda's Romance to True in ME3 right before I meet her for the third time in the apartment so I can trigger the romance dialog option. I have found ID Values for most of the characters besides Miranda.

#### Romance Value ID's for MS3

1. Miranda  - ?????
2. Liara    - 19722
3. Ashley   - 19724
4. Kaidan   - 19723
5. Tali     - 19726
6. Garrus   - 19725
7. Samantha - 19835
8. Cortez   - 19838

Comment: Try some numbers around.d the 19720 mark, most if the other characters are in there.

Comment: I would like to know this to some one give a better answer. PLEASE!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you want to trigger the romance scene for Miranda in the apartments, you have to make sure your Shepard is not locked in any relationship. This mean all "TrueLove" plot IDs must not be set (Liara, Tali, etc). In addition to the one you've listed:

### TrueLove Plot IDs

- **Miranda: 21750**
- **Jack: 19846**

Answer (score 3):

I did this right before the 3rd meeting with Miranda.  I used the Gibbed's Mass Effect 3 Save Editor.  I applied all of the following settings and it worked.  It has an early and a late section, but I just did them both late.

(edited from original comment by jamespra...@dodo.com.au in the GME3SE FAQ)

before you meet at citadel docking bay 24d - early in the game

SET

id: 5209, name: "Romanced Miranda",BOOL YES

id: 3304, name: "Broke Up with Miranda",BOOL NO

INT: 266, name: "Romance state with Miranda",INT 5 (so 266, then in the next box 5)

id: 177, name: "Miranda is loyal",BOOL YES

id: 33, name: "Miranda acquired",BOOL YES

id: 195, name: "Miranda is dead",BOOL NO

or later in the game

id: 21750, name: "Miranda - romanced",BOOL YES

id: 20184, name: "Miranda - warned",BOOL YES

id: 20278, name: "Miranda - killed"},BOOL NO

Enjoy the complete and total rip off that is the sex scene with Miranda in ME3.

Answer (score 0):

Miranda's Romance ID is:

## 19731

(inferred from [this post on the bioware forums](http://social.bioware.com/%252525C2%252525A0social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/325/index/7625998/611))

Comment: There's always an additional (and distinct) plot ID that's cleared when the "TrueLove" event for a given romance option is activated, so I don't think this ID has anything to do with Miranda.

Comment: @TimStone If you read that post, and the context that number is presented in, you'll see that it *is* to do with `TrueLove` values, and all the other values mentioned are exactly the same as the values mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, but this value is specific to Tali's `TrueLove` option. In addition to clearing the values for the other romance options, Tali's clears 19731, Liara's clears 19727, Ashley's clears 19729, Kaidan's clears 19728, and so on and so forth. So 19731 having to do with Miranda is unlikely, otherwise they'd all clear 19731. It's more likely to be an additional character-specific plot variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just change ID 21751 at bool to False if you broke up with Miranda.

Source: https://fextralife.com/forums/t447870/how-to-save-miranda--a-complete-guide

I will change the setting back after the quest, because I don't know what exactly it is used for. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/324424)