# Changing Miranda's fate in Mass Effect 3 with 'Gibbed Save Editor'?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've missed the last meeting with Miranda and now she dies every time I go to the Sanctuary. What should I change with the Gibbed Save Editor to save her? I didn't romance her. My female Shepard couldn't even if she wanted.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/65355/21759)  seems to suggest that "id: 20184, name: "Miranda - warned",BOOL YES" could be a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

fulfill several conditions as described here: http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/355/index/10437334/5, but I additionally had to change another parameter BOOL {id: 21750, name: "Miranda - romanced "} set YES. As far as I could understand, if you could not stand the save of ME2, then on the story she dies anyway (will not be satisfied "Miranda - romanced"). So if you play without save from ME2, then set id: 21750 solve your problem.
Here are some useful links
1) http://code.google.com/p/me3tools/wiki/FAQ#...other_questions_about_editing_plot

Comment: It would be better to actually describe what needs to be done than linking to a confusing topic on Bioware's forums.

Answer (score 0):

Change ID 21751 at bool to "False" if you broke up with Miranda as described [here](https://fextralife.com/forums/t447870/how-to-save-miranda--a-complete-guide).

Comment: What exactly will that do? And can you tell us how that relates to the other answers here?